# Excel string to HTML code / inserting text mid string

Tags: html, excel, string

How do I insert text (a URL link) from another cell (B1) into this cell (C1) containing HTML code like this:

<h4>Features</h4><ul><li><a href="" target="blank">Available in other fabrics</a></li></ul>

Note: 
- The insert text should fill in the  tag.
- I tried using concat strings and convert the " into &CHAR(32) but it's not working.
- I have a few thousand rows of this data to work thru. Each URL link is different depending on the productSKU. So this process has to be automated.
- I am not familar with VB.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible that you edit your question and add more information on how your spreadsheet looks?

Comment: You could use this formula, assuming `C1` contains: `<div>
  <h4>Features</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=FIXURL target="blank">Available in other fabrics</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>`.  In `A1`, use: `=SUBSTITUTE(C1,"FIXURL",B1)`

Comment: Try with " as char(34) - it should work.

Answer (score 0):

So it should be something  like

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1,CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),CHAR(34)&B1&CHAR(34))
```

assuming the "" only occurs in the href tag.

It's easier than the alternative which would be

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1,"""""",""""&B1&"""")
```

(you have to type a pair of double quotes for each double quote you want)

You might consider defining a name (say q) as =char(34) then it would be

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1,q&q,q&B1&q)
```